# How to use table2excel.js plugin to download HTML table into Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I'm using the table2excel.js plugin to download an HTML table to Excel, in JavaScript. When I download the table, I get the message: "Excel cannot open the file 'Test.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file." When I manually change the name of the downloaded file to 'Test.xls', I'm able to open the file fine (with a small warning that the file format and extension don't match).

Here is the link to table2excel.js: [https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/blob/377b933ae6b04f4c1826acc24a2bb0a049933f8b/dist/jquery.table2excel.js](http://table2excel)

Some of the things I've tried:
1. I changed  e.uri from "e.uri = data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," to "e.uri = "data:application/msexcel;base64,"
2. I changed
. . .   'return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xlsx"'; to
. . . 'return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls"';
(when making this change, the file was saved as Test.xls.xlsx and still had the same problem opening the .xlsx file).

How can I get the file to save as .xls rather than xlsx? Or is there a way to make this work while still saving the file as .xlsx (presumably by matching the format with the .xlsx extension)?

Note: if it matters, the file Test.xlsx is "plain vanilla" with just text in a bunch of cells. There's no fancy formatting, characters, etc. The text is all Alphanumeric, with just a few special characters such as : ",.#'/@"

Many thanks if any ideas!

Comment: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, that didn't work. Still same problem.

Comment: Are you writing the `Base64` string to a file?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the "Base64" string is or does. I'm fairly new to all this. The only thing I'm trying to write to the excel file is the contents of the table. Do you know how Excel tries to interpret whether a spreadsheet file format matches the extension .xls or .xlsx?

Comment: What do you see if you open the output in Notepad?  If there are no "special" characters then you've written the `Base64` output to the file instead of the Excel document.

Comment: i changed the .xlsx to .xls in jquery.table2excel.js file in getFileName function and also clear all cookies in the browser it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem too, I changed the following method in `jquery.table2excel.js` to:

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
}
```

I am able to open the xls file after that but a different format file extension message will prompt, perhaps changing the header will do.

Comment: Excel is opening properly but how to remove that warning ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the source js file, I had to change

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
}
```

To

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great plugin, but it has a bug that stops it working.

Thankfully, since it's javascript, you can correct it yourself.

Load up the jquery.table2excel.js file into a text editor.

Around line 130 you'll find the function called, getFileName.

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
}
```

Correct it to:

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.name ? settings.name : "Untitled") + ".xls";
}
```

I guess the author couldn't decide what to name their variables.

Sadly, you will always get a warning about the file format being incorrect for the extension. This is because an xls file is usually a binary file, but table2excel exploits the feature of excel where it can load html.